# Automating RealTerm with Python

Tags: python, winsock, pywin32

I am currently in the process of creating a script to automate RealTerm. I need to send a binary file and have the Winsock setting set to "Raw". RealTerms documentation indicates that I need an integer 0 or 1 for this setting but I am receiving a "object has no attribute" "Winsock".

`RT.Winsock = 0` is what I currently have it set at. This this is the error message I get. `'<win32com.gen_py.Realterm Library.IRealtermIntf instance at 0x1826368502752>' object has no attribute 'Winsock'` Could this be a bug in the program?

I have also tried `RT.Winsock = ("0")` and that returned the same error but that sets it as a string and not integer.

Any thoughts on how it should be set or what I'm doing wrong?
Here is my full error below.

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'<win32com.gen_py.Realterm Library.IRealtermIntf instance at 0x2390257155040>' object has no attribute 'Winsock'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "C:\NetworkUpdater\NUP\NUPv1.0.py", line 13, in module
RT.Winsock = 0

Edit: Added code below

```
RT = DispatchEx("Realterm.RealtermIntf")
RT.Visible = True
RT.Caption = "Realterm Controlled from Python"
RT.SelectTabSheet("Port")
RT.Winsock = 0
```

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the code and the full traceback error.

Comment: I have added the information you requested.

Comment: Which version of RealTerm are you using?

Comment: I am using V3.0.1.44. I had also previously tried V2.0.0.70

Comment: After a quick look online, this page suggests that Winsock is a valid property: https://realterm.sourceforge.io/#COM_Properties ie `property Winsock: Integer dispid 209;`. Assume you are using `win32com.client.DispatchEx()` ... generally people just use `Dispatch()`.  My guess is that your cached interface to this object is out of date (Winsock seems a later addition to the type library). You might try deleting this cache. For me the directory is in `$HomeDir\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7` : delete all the files in this folder (or simply reboot your machine perhaps).

Comment: Also, try a COM/OLE Object Viewer to see what is actually available in the object. There is an Object Browser available in the Excel VBA IDE, or ole2view.exe in the Windows SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the input, so I you are correct I am using `DispatchEX()`. I also did look in the in the Object Browser in Excel VBA IDE and it listed Winsock "Property Winsock As Long Member of RealTerm.RealTerminft" Which left me a little more confused as I tried to look at other examples that were "As Long" as well and couldn't get my code to execute.

But I am going to try and clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get `RT.Winsock` to properly work or even use the `DoCommands` due to lack of examples even though it was in the documentation.

But I was able to resolve this issue and get the Wisock setting to Raw by setting `WINSOCK=0` in a INI file that gets called upon startup of realterm.exe